# Add `active` class to li of current single page wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Looking for your help and advices. 
I have a list of links to `single` in Wordpress. I need to place class `active` only to li of active page.

Should be like on this image [image]

But it is:

[image]

My wp-code:

```
<ul class="inline-list medium-6 large-4 skill-items">
<?php 
    $id = get_the_ID();
    // echo $id;
    $class;
    $skills = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'skills',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        ));
    if ($skills->have_posts()) : while ($skills->have_posts()) : $skills->the_post();   
    // echo $post->ID;
    if( $id == $post->ID) {$class = 'active';} else {$class = '';}
    ?>
    <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
?>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try using the class `current-menu-item` of wordpress

Comment: Dont even think about storing your nav menu items in a CPT and loop over it. just use the standard `nav_menu` and the correct answer I provided to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the proper way to do a menu in Wordpress. You should use [`wp_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) instead of doing a custom `WP_Query`.

First, in *functions.php* add the following to [register a new menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu):

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu');
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('skills_menu', __( 'Skills menu', 'your-theme-name' ));
}
```

Then log in your administration, you will see that new menu placement under Appearance > Menu. Create a new menu for that placement - you have the possibility to automatically add top level new pages to this menu.

Then in your template add the following in order to display the menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'skills_menu')); ?>
```

[Wordpress will automatically handle the active class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Current-Page_Menu_Items) by adding `current-menu-item` to the appropriate `li`. No need for any filter for that.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer for my question using `Javascript/jQuery`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var pgurl = window.location.href;
$("ul.skill-items li").each(function(){
  if($(this).find('a').attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).find('a').attr("href") == '' )
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
});
```

`pgurl` contains your current url. After that for each item we are looking for `anchor` and its link. Then we are comapring those links, and if their are equal, we add class `active` to `li`

Answer (score -1):

You may try this:

```
function my_alter_classes_on_li( $classes, $item ){
    global $post;
    if( in_array( $post->post_type, $classes ) ) $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_alter_classes_on_li', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Found answer using jQuery, will post as answer

Comment: @vard If so, he/she is wrong. there is no reason someone does not use such a usefull thing. the answer I provided does not need such a silly thing, jQuery , etc. workaround. If he needs the correct answer, I provided one

Comment: @Trix Not really, for two reason: 1. you didn't pointed out that he should use `wp_nav_menu`  and 2. you don't need a filter to add the active class as it is [automatically handle](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Current-Page_Menu_Items).

Comment: It is not automatically handled for single posts of CPTs. give it a try man ;)

Comment: @Trix That's true for ancestor page only - if you link directly a single post in your menu the active class will be correctly added. I suggest you to give it a try.